# Do lawyers have to prove their claim that they represent an entity?

Tags: united-states, legal-representation

I got a threatening letter from lawyer Y the other day. They claim they are representing company X. Since I wasn't sure, I wrote back, asking for documentation of their retention by company X. I also wrote directly to company X asking if they had retained Y as their lawyer.

No response.

Does a lawyer have to provide documentation that they are representing the company they say they are?

Comment: Lawyers are specifically forbidden from lying about who they represent.  (https://www.americanbar.org/groups/professional_responsibility/publications/model_rules_of_professional_conduct/rule_4_1_truthfulness_in_statements_to_others/comment_on_rule_4_1/)  If you can demonstrate that this lawyer does not in fact represent this client, then they are risking serious sanctions up to being disbarred.

Comment: And otherwise, they have no obligation to you. I would not expect either the company or the lawyer to cooperate with you, so you should communicate with them via your attorney.

Comment: @abelenky -- Good answer: you should post it as such!